# Интеграция Contact Form 7 в шаблон страницы WordPress без <?php wp_head(); ?> и <?php wp_footer(); ?>

Tags: wordpress, ajax, плагин, contact-form7

Возникла следующая проблема: в шаблоне страницы сайта на WP не используются `<?php wp_head(); ?> и <?php wp_footer(); ?>`
После установки плагина Contact Form 7 и подключения и настройки формы на странице она полностью работает, но не в режиме отправки AJAX, что не позволяет настроить события через DOM в частности переадресацию после отправки формы на другую страницу сайта. Вопрос в том, что именно необходимо напрямую "зашить" в шаблон страницы по плагину или WP, без использования `<?php wp_head(); ?> и <?php wp_footer(); ?>` чтобы форма подхватила AJAX?

Comment: Без wp_head и wp_footer у тебя много чего не будет работать. Не выёживайся и делай правильно.

Comment: Все что необходимо как раз настроено и работает как нужно, кроме Contact Form 7, иначе бы не спрашивал. Стоит именно такая задача, так что я не выеживаюсь, а испытываю необходимость в решении.

Comment: Ты не понимаешь как работает ВП и соответственно чем чреваты такие костыли. Не говоря уже о безумии (за каким, извините, х.. фигом ) избавляться от критически важных функций.

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос решен, если кому понадобится, то достаточно в футере "зашить"

```js
<script id='contact-form-7-js-extra'>
var wpcf7 = {"api":{"root":"http:\/\/ваш_сайт\/wp-json\/","namespace":"contact-form-7\/v1"}};
</script>
<script src='http://ваш_сайт/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/index.js?ver=5.5.6' id='contact-form-7-js'></script>
```

Comment: Это пример как делать нельзя.

Comment: А что собственно не так в данном случае? Почему так делать нельзя? Просто потому, что… ? Функции wp_head и wp_footer ничего такого критически-важного не несут в себе, кроме как подтягивают скрипты да стили. Если мне этот мусорный зачастую функционал не нужен, то можно вшить в шаблон только то что мне нужно, а не сидеть отключать все это через ремув…

Comment: Ты отрезал ногу и руку, вставив вместо них костыли и спрашиваешь "а что не так"? Попробуй сам подумать. Документация в помощь. Это же касается про "подтягивает ненужное". Уже совершенная ошибка XY. А по коду - даже подключение скриптов неправильное.

Comment: Нога, рука… Это все образы не имеющие никакой конкретики. Я же объяснил, что все что нужно вытащено было. То, что не нужно по стилям и обработкам осталось за пределами. Что не так с подключением скрипта? Укажите ошибку, если вы ее видите, а не «неправильно» не так… Скрипты подключены ровно так, как их отдаёт сам wp_footer Конструктивнее можно к вопросу подходить?

Comment: Это не образы, а совершено прямые аналогии. Ты их не понимаешь потому что не знаешь как работает ВП. Не знаешь основ. Даже формирование урлов и как нужно подключать скрипты и то не знаешь. А про "конструктивнее" - комменты не предназначены для этого. Задашь правильный вопрос отдельно - получишь ответ.

Comment: Вы так никакой конкретики и не привели кроме общих слов, которые указывают на низкий уровень ваших собственных представлений о принципах работы ВП. Если вам не понятен вопрос, то вам вам простая интерпретация: 1) какой «критический» функционал несут wp_head и wp_footer, который я не смог бы подключить мимо них? 2) что не так с подключением скриптов в моем примере? (или вы считаете, что сам wp_footer некорректно их отдаёт?) Читайте выше, скрипты подключены ровно так, как их отдаёт сам wp_footer. Вы похоже как раз специалист по типовым задачам и любое отступление в сторону ставит вас в тупик.

Comment: На бис: комментарии на SO не предназначены для обсуждений и вопросов. Есть вопрос - задавай как того требуют правила ресурса.

Comment: Все понятно, профи… слив засчитан… Иди школьников учи как ВП юзать…

Comment: Незнающий может поумнеть, дурак - никогда. Удачи.